# javascript filter method query

Tags: javascript, html, filter

I am trying to understand the `filter` method in JavaScript.

I have an array and with a checkbox and a global variable I want to control what to show in the array.

If the checkbox is unchecked and the value of the variable `filterTodos` is false (false is default), I want to show all the items of the array. If the checkbox is checked and the variable value of variable filterTodos is true, I want to only show the tasks that are not complete. (`completed: false`)

I know that my code for the filter method is wrong as it's not doing anything, and when the checkbox is unchecked it displays the array multiple times.

This is my code:

```js
let todos = [{
  text: 'Order airline tickets',
  completed: false
}, {
  text: 'Vaccine appointment',
  completed: true
}, {
  text: 'Order Visa',
  completed: true
}, {
  text: 'Book hotell',
  completed: false
}, {
  text: 'Book taxi to airport',
  completed: true
}]

let filterTodos = false

showTodos(todos);

function addTodo(add_todo) {
  let p = document.createElement('p')
  p.textContent = add_todo.text
  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(p)
  let checkBox = document.createElement("input")
  let label = document.createElement("label")
  checkBox.type = "checkbox"
  checkBox.value = addTodo.completed
  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(checkBox)

  //create variable to generate random id for radiobutton
  const id = Math.random().toString(36)

  checkBox.setAttribute("name", id)

  //Switch loop over the completed
  switch (add_todo.completed) {
    case true:
      checkBox.setAttribute("checked", "true") // Mark true button as checked
      break
    case false:
      checkBox.setAttribute("unchecked", "false") // Mark false button as checked
      break
    default:
      break
  }

  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(label)
  label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(add_todo.completed))
}

function showTodos(show_todos) {
  //function to show the whole object
  show_todos.forEach(function(todo) {
    addTodo(todo);
  })
}

function unComplete(uncompleteTodos) {
  unComplete.filter(!todo.completed)

}

function hideCompleted() {
  document.querySelector("#filterTodo").addEventListener('change', function(e) {

    if (document.getElementById('filterTodo').checked) {
      filterTodos = true;
      console.log(filterTodos);
      filterTodos = todos.filter(unComplete)
      unComplete(todos)
    } else {
      filterTodos = false;
      console.log(filterTodos);
      showTodos(todos)

    }
  })
}
```

```html
<h1>Todos</h1>
<label style="font: bold 1.5em courier !important">
     <input type="checkbox" id="filterTodo" onChange="hideCompleted()">Hide completed
     </label><br><br>
<input id="search-todo" type="text" placeholder="Search todo">
<button id="reset-search" type="reset" value="reset" onclick="window.location.reload()">New search</button>

<div id="todos"></div>
<form action="" id="addTodo">
  <input type="text" name="inputTodo" placeholder="Insert new todo">
  <button>Add Todo</button>
</form>

<script src="js/index2.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are making a mistake. When the `hideCompleted()` will be called it will call `showTodos()` and then it will call `addTodo()` and hence it will add new items means items will be double

Comment: You've created all sorts of problems for yourself that a little attention to detail could resolve. First, you have an `onChange` attribute on the checkbox that calls a function that sets another `change` handler that does the same thing. Secondly, you use `filter()` properly in one part of your code, but then try to run a `forEach()` loop on something that doesnt' exist - that shows up as an error in the console. You can start by fixing those first.

Comment: `function unComplete(uncompleteTodos) {
  unComplete.filter(!todo.completed)
}` also not works. You cannot filter the function

Comment: @RandyCasburn thanks, I didn't know that of the filter function, I have taken away the loop and just use:
uncompleteTodos.filter(!todos.completed)
and its still faulty. Could you please alter the code, so I understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One step to resolve your bug, it's to make your code a minimal verifiable functionality of what you want to do. Then you have a pretty clear picture of what's going on. You can grab a piece of paper write the flux of your program as well.

Breaking down your code we have:

1. initial assignment of `todos` array, `filterTodos` bool control var and `showTodos` to add them to the page.
2. function `addTodo`: **add** a `todo` to the page
3. function `showTodos`: iterates `todos` to calling `addTodo`

By now, we are ok, considering just the flux. Then we have:

4. function `unComplete`: **just return `todos` array filtered with `completed: false`. It does nothing on the HTML**
5. function `hideCompleted`: onchange event of each HTML element of `todo`, where if it's:

   -- checked: just call `unComplete` resulting on **0 changes to the HTML**.

   -- unchecked: calls again `showTodos` **adding again all `todos` to the HTML**.

You have many ways to resolve this issue. I'm showing just the maybe stupidest one then you can improve it as your wish:

```js
 
let todos = [{
  text: 'Order airline tickets',
  completed: false
}, {
  text: 'Book taxi to airport',
  completed: true
}]

init();

// ----------

function addTodo(add_todo, index) {
  let checkBox = document.createElement("input")
  checkBox.type = "checkbox"
  checkBox.id = 'chk' + index

  let label = document.createElement("label")
  label.appendChild(checkBox)
  label.innerHTML += add_todo.text

  let li = document.createElement("li")
  li.appendChild(label)

  document.getElementById('todosList').appendChild(li)
  document.getElementById(checkBox.id).checked = add_todo.completed
}

function addAllTodos(show_todos) {
  show_todos.forEach(function(todo, index) {
    addTodo(todo, index);
  })
}

function showTodo(li){
  li.style.display = 'list-item'
}
function hideTodo(li){
  li.style.display = 'none'
}

function showOnlyUncompletedTodo(li) {
  if (li.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').checked) {
    hideTodo(li)
  }
  else {
    showTodo(li)
  }
}

function hideCompleted() {
  func = this.checked ? showOnlyUncompletedTodo : showTodo
  document.querySelectorAll('#todosList li').forEach(func)
}

function init(){
  document.getElementById("hideCompleted").addEventListener('change', hideCompleted)
  document.getElementById("btnAddTodo").addEventListener('click', function(){
    let todo = {
      text: document.getElementById('inputNewTodo').value,
      completed: false
    }

    todos.push(todo)
    addTodo(todo, todos.length - 1)
  })

  addAllTodos(todos);
}
```

```css
.todos-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Todos</h1>
    <label style="font: bold 1.5em courier !important">
      <input type="checkbox" id="hideCompleted"> Hide completed
    </label><br><br>
    <input id="search-todo" type="text" placeholder="Search todo">
    <button id="reset-search" type="reset" value="reset" onclick="window.location.reload()">New search</button>

    <div id="todos"></div>
    <form id="addTodo" onsubmit="return false">
      <input type="text" id="inputNewTodo" name="inputTodo" placeholder="Insert new todo">
      <button id="btnAddTodo">Add Todo</button>
    </form>
    <br>

    <ul id="todosList" class="todos-list">

    </ul>

     <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your input, but I really need to save it with filter method, but your code gave me some valuable ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

Filter method takes all the items of an array and loops 
through it. For example:

```
var words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];
const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);
```

Will only return items from the array with length greater than 6.

So i that that you want:
`completeTodos.filter(todo => todo.completed)` it will return only completed todos.

Comment: Its the uncompleted todos that are the problem